# How do I check the results of a modulo division for every item in a list and check if every number satisfies a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I realize my question title might be a little confusing so I'll give context. I have code where it first generates a random number, then it creates a list based on that random number where the range is (random number, random number + 15).

What I want to do is create an if statement where if every item within that range can not be divided by an inputted number then it would return as `True` and then carry out whatever is supposed to happen then. (I'm using Python 3 for this)

For example, if my list is `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` and my inputted number is 5, then it should check if every number in there **doesn't** have a remainder of 0 (in this case, the list wouldn't satisfy this condition as `10 % 5 == 0`). Because this isn't the case here, the code would then look to the else statement.

I had a few ideas but none of them are working. I'll list out the two I remember off of the top of my head.

```
if all(x % distance == 0 for x in jagX):
```

and

```
if (all(jagX) % distance == 0):
```

For some reason, these always returned a true even though I purposefully used inputs that should cause these if statements to be false every time (I would make distance be 2 as a test to see if this recognizes when the statement is false)

Comment: Why are you testing if the remainder *is* zero?

Comment: I was making a counter that added to a variable every time any of the values within the range got intercepted by a 'line' across the x-axis and the y-axis and so I was using the line distance and dividing the values in the variables by it

Answer (score 0):

If you use `any()` with a generator expression, this can be built like:

#### Code:

```
def test_zero_modulo_in_list(list_to_test, modulo):
    return not any(i % modulo == 0 for i in list_to_test)
```

#### Test Code:

```
a_list = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

print(test_zero_modulo_in_list(a_list, 5))
print(test_zero_modulo_in_list(a_list, 13))
```

#### Results:

```
False
True
```

Comment: The thing I love most about computer science is how it has limitless satisfaction for people who like to tinker. I admit, I was going to reply to your comment a couple of hours ago asking if you could explain the whole thing to me because I didn't understand it at all by looking at it.

I thought "test_zero_module_in_list" was a python syntax that meant something, like any() or int(), you get the idea lol. However, I messed around what you replied and I love it! I 100% understand what it's doing and I'm so proud of myself for being able to get it. Thank you so much! :)